# How to print 1-10,11-20 and so on number of rows of a file in loop using shell?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file consisting of 4000 rows, I need to iterate the records of that file over shell script and extract first 10 rows and send that rows to my java code which i already wrote, and then next 10 rows and so on

Comment: [edit] your question to clairfy: When you say `send that rows` - do you mean pipe them or pass them as arguments or open some kind of ssh channel or something else? At least show how your java script would be called with one instance of 10 rows.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass 10 lines at a time as arguments to your script:

```
< file xargs -d$'\n' -n 10 myscript
```

To pipe 10 lines at a time as input to your script:

```
< file xargs -d$'\n' -n 10 sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@" | myscript' {}
```

Assuming your input is in a file named `file` which I'm creating with 30 instead of 4000 lines of input:

```
$ seq 30 > file
```

and modifying to have some lines that contain spaces, some that contain shell variables, and some that contain regexp and globbing chars to show no type of shell expansion is being done:

```
$ head -10 file
1
here    is a multi-field   line
3
4
$HOME
6
.*
8
9
10
```

Here's 10 args at a time being passed to an awk script:

```
$ < file xargs -d$'\n' -n 10 awk 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) print i, "<" ARGV[i] ">"; exit} END{print "---"}'
1 <1>
2 <here    is a multi-field   line>
3 <3>
4 <4>
5 <$HOME>
6 <6>
7 <.*>
8 <8>
9 <9>
10 <10>
---
1 <11>
2 <12>
3 <13>
4 <14>
5 <15>
6 <16>
7 <17>
8 <18>
9 <19>
10 <20>
---
1 <21>
2 <22>
3 <23>
4 <24>
5 <25>
6 <26>
7 <27>
8 <28>
9 <29>
10 <30>
---
```

and here's 10 lines of input at a time being passed to an awk script:

```
$ < file xargs -d$'\n' -n 10 sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@" | awk '\''{print NR, "<" $0 ">"} END{print "---"}'\''' {}
1 <1>
2 <here    is a multi-field   line>
3 <3>
4 <4>
5 <$HOME>
6 <6>
7 <.*>
8 <8>
9 <9>
10 <10>
---
1 <11>
2 <12>
3 <13>
4 <14>
5 <15>
6 <16>
7 <17>
8 <18>
9 <19>
10 <20>
---
1 <21>
2 <22>
3 <23>
4 <24>
5 <25>
6 <26>
7 <27>
8 <28>
9 <29>
10 <30>
---
```

Comment: Can you explain sir plz

Comment: What part of it don't you understand after reading the `xargs` man page?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that OP wants to pass lines as an argument to OP's code if that is the case then could you please try following once(haven't tested it by running it since I don't have OP's java code etc).

```
awk '
FNR%10==0{
   system("your_java_code " value OFS $0)
   value=""
}
{
   value=(value?value OFS:"")$0
}
END{
   if(value){
     system("your_java_code " value)
   }
}
'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '
{
   value=(value?value OFS:"")$0
}
FNR%10==0{
   system("your_java_code " value)
   value=""
}
END{
   if(value){
     system("your_java_code " value)
   }
}
'  Input_file
```

***PS:*** Just for safer side, I kept `END` section of `awk` code so that in case there are left over lines(let's say total number of lines are NOT completely divided by 10) then it will call java program with remaining lines to it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel -kN10 javaProgram :::: file
```

This will pass the lines 1-10, 11-20, ... as arguments to program `javaProgram`

If you want to pass 10 lines at time, use:

```
parallel -kN10 --cat javaProgram :::: file
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
for ((i=0; i<=4000; i+=10)); do
    arr=( ) # create a new empty array
    for ((j=$i; j<=i+10; j++)); do
        arr+=( $j ) # add id to array
    done
    printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" # or execute command with all the id
done
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit plz

Comment: It's just arithmetic

Comment: Added some comments

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to slice out rows from a file, then pipe those rows to java. This interpretation differs from the other answers, so let me know if I'm not understanding you:

```
$ file=/etc/services
$ count=$(wc -l < "${file}")
$ start=1
$ stride=10
$ for ((i=start; i<=count; i+=stride)); do
  awk -v i="${i}" -v stride="${stride}" \
    'NR > (i+stride) { exit } NR >= i && NR < (i + stride)' "${file}" \
    | java ...
done
```

`file` holds the path to the data rows. `count` is the total count of rows in that file. `start` is the first row, `stride` is how many you want to slice out in each iteration.

The for loop then performs the stride addition, while `awk` slices out the rows so numbered. We pipe them to the `java` program on standard in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are passing the 10 lines groups from your file to your script as command line arguments, this is an answer:

```
rows=4000 # the number of rows in file
groupsize=10 # the size of lines groups

OIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n' # use newline as input field separator to avoid `for` splitting on spaces
groups=$(($rows / $groupsize)) # the number of groups of lines
for i in $(seq 1 $groups); do # loop through each group of lines
  from=$((($i * $groupsize) - $groupsize + 1))
  to=$(($i * $groupsize))
  # build the arguments for each script invocation by concatenating each group of lines
  for line in `sed -n -e ${from},${to}p file`; do # 'file' is your input file name
    arguments=$arguments \"$line\"
  done
  echo script $arguments # remove echo and change 'script' with your script name
done    
IFS="$OIFS" # restore original input field separator
```